# Infinite while loop in std::thread raising CPU usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I have an infinite while loop executing in an `std::thread` in my C++ program. When doing this, my program uses up 45% op my CPU (according to task manager). When 'throttling' the loop using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1))`, the CPU usage goes down to 12%' but, of course, this solution is far from optimal, especially considering the fact that I'm developing a game. How can I lower the CPU usage without sleeping the thread, since I need it to be available whenever an if-condition (which is placed inside the loop) is true?

Comment: Have the loop only execute as often as is needed. How often would you like to run this loop? Games are tied to control rate, physics tics, or frame rate (whichever is natural for you). I'd use a `sleep_until` call that is updated on each loop iteration. That's the easy way, at least. The better solution is to use a gaming framework.

Comment: @JohnFilleau the loop is inside a thread which is part of a threadpool class, I need it to be looping constantly, checking for tasks to execute.

Comment: @Serket Use a `std::condition_variable` to "wake up" the thread only when tasks are available.

Comment: Do you need it to loop constantly and check for threads to execute, or do you need it to only be awake when a task needs execution? This is a producer/consumer paradigm. Use a `std::condition_variable` and wait on it until a task is ready or some shutdown signal is received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your thread wait for a condition variable (`std::condition_variable`) and notify it when changing the flag.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use std::condition_variable?

Comment: @Serket Good documentation always has a good example. Here's some good documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable